# c# application version

Tags: c#, installation

i have just completed a c# program version 1.0.0.0 and made an installer using the built-in visual studio set-up project. i have noticed that in add/remove programs the version is 1.0.0 which corresponds to the installer properties. It rather misleading for an end user and I don't appear to be able to make the number 1.0.0.0 i.e. the same as my actual application as it is limited to 3 digits. Why the 2 different numbers?

thanks
Damo

Comment: You just left the installer's Version property at its default, "1.0.0".  It is just a string, you can make it anything you want.  Simply change it and add ".0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned the two are different things and you can set them independently of each other...

[image]

...by going to the project properties and clicking the Assembly Information button.  In the case of my example the * in the third  box means that the Assembly version build number increments each day.

Comment: No.  File version is again completely different.  We are talking about Installer Application version vs .NET Assembly version.

Answer (score 2):

Windows application versioning (What you are seeing in Add/Remove programs) and .NET assembly versioning (your .NET assembly version - right click executable > Properties in windows explorer) are **two different things**.  They do not necessarily correspond to one another.

The .NET Assembly version number is formatted like this:

```
<major version>.<minor version>.<build number>.<revision>
```

This corresponds to your application assembly in .NET.

The windows installer your using is the built in .NET Installer project?  There are multiple ways to make Windows installers like WiX, InstallShield and some of them allow entering of version numbers differently, including alpha-numeric.

Comment: so which one of them is the version of the application? sounds like it is 1.0.0 but my help - about shows (and indeed so does the default about form within visual studio) 1.0.0.0

Comment: Version of your .NET application assembly is 1.0.0.0.  Version of the Windows application (Known to Windows) is 1.0.0.  The latter will be used to determine if a newer version is available and upgradable (for the installer program), former is purely .NET assembly version and nothing to do with the installer.